# sed statement syntax wrong?

Tags: sed

My sed only works if the input file last entry is 'in', how would I get it to work if file has 'in' or 'out'? I've tried different variations with no success.

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/'
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/ out/ out/'
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/ || out/ out/'
```

#### input file

```
Apr 6 08:54:23 TCP 212.58.244.58:80 in

Apr 6 09:29:09 TCP 212.58.244.58:443 out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* \(in\|out\)/ \1/'
```

See [sed regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have3 examples:

1. `egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/'`

   This should work on lines ending `in`.
2. `egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/ out/ out/'`

   This will fail with syntax errors from `sed`.  The first part is a valid `s///` command, up to the slash after the second `in`; the rest should be a new command, such as:

   ```
   egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/; s/:[^:]* out/ out/'
   ```

   That should work on `in` and `out` with any version of `sed`.
3. `egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/ || out/ out/'`

   As with the previous diagnosis, the material after the first `s///` is simply not valid `sed`.

Standard [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) uses a moderately power version of regular expressions, but it is not the full ERE (extended regular expression).  In particular, it does not support alternation (or'd alternatives).

Some modern versions of `sed` (notably GNU `sed`) support ERE and even PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions).

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed -r 's/:[^:]* (in|out)/ \1/'
```

Failing that, to process 'in' and 'out' with a single substitute, you could use:

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* \([io][nu]t\{0,1\}\)/ \1/'
```

Granted, that will map `on` and `iut` and `int` and so on as well as `in` and `out`; the question for you would be 'could such oddities occur in your data'?  If so, then the two explicit `s///` commands is better.

Finally, all the regular expressions might benefit from a `$` after the `in` or `out` to ensure the substitution only occurs at the end of the line.

Comment: good explanation. i went with egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' denied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/; s/:[^:]* out/ out/' since I know my firewalls will only log 'in' or 'out'  works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/\<\(TCP\|UDP\)\>/!d;s/:[^:]*\(in\|out\)/ \1/' denied.txt
Apr 6 08:54:23 TCP 212.58.244.58 in
Apr 6 09:29:09 TCP 212.58.244.58 out
```

Or more simply:

```
sed '/\<\(TCP\|UDP\)\>/!d;s/:[^ ]*//2' denied.txt
Apr 6 08:54:23 TCP 212.58.244.58 in
Apr 6 09:29:09 TCP 212.58.244.58 out
```